# Get Message in PHP

Tags: php, url, get

I'm trying very simple in PHP and not very sure what to search here or on google.

Problem is -

In PHP function I want to call/get a URL

> http://www.example.com/message?Name=MyNameIsX

and like to read the return value (body) at this URL (which may contain "Your Name is MyNameIsX")

I tried

> $data = file_get_contents($url)

This is timing out; although I'm able to open the $url in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, file_get_contents normal use for files on this server and base on support and setting this perhaps is not allow.

See PHP CUrl http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php or example
http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php, http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

Comment: Good, and as a good rule also, never trust data that you get from a other server, or you server for it mater, also verify and strip the data before insert into database or show for the use.

Answer (score 1):

You could use cUrl as suggested by FIG-GHD742 but I find the [HTTP extension](http://lt.php.net/manual/en/book.http.php) a lot easier to use. It's newer and has a neat OOP api.

Another method is that you can actually do an include/require with these, but it's generally a bad idea to do so if you don't control the source from which the data is coming

Comment: No good ide to use include/require, base on the read data will be read as PHP scoure files and can include bad script that run on you server.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to enable loopback calls on the server (self-calls). It would be better to get the data on the backend if you need it on the same server. Via a PHP API or calls to a database.

Comment: I would add that you can use Javascript to do this without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

**

- This will help you lot : http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php
  http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php, 
  http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

**

Answer (score -1):

Yes the above answers is right. some hosting providers disable it for security purpose. You may also try fopen(php) if you are not looking for Curl way. Read documentation here http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php